# Is improper integral $\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{x}dx$ convergence?

Tags: integration

Is $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{x}dx$ an improper integral?

I suppose it is proper since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan x}{x}=1$, so the function is bounded as $x\to 0$, but I am not sure because it is however undefined at $x=0$. In this case how do I prove its convergence?

Thank you!

Comment: The integral is known as [Catalan's constant, G](https://brilliant.org/wiki/catalans-constant/). See also [A006752](https://oeis.org/A006752).

Comment: The fact that a function is not well-defined at a set of points of measure $0$ does not matter.

Comment: The function défined by $f(x)=\dfrac{\arctan x}{x}$ for $x\in ]0;1]$ has a continuous continuation on $[0,1]$ thus the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\arctan x}{x}\,dx$ does exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some (easy) asymptotic analysis:

Since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan x}{x}=1$, we have the equivalence of functions:
$$\frac{\arctan x}x\sim_0 1. $$
Now the constant function $1$ has a convergent integral on $[0,1]$, hence the given  integral  is convergent.

(A result in asymptotic analysis asserts that the integrals of two equivalent positive functions both converge or both diverge.)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the integral as,

$$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{x}dx= \arctan x\ln x\bigg|_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx
=\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx$$

Note $ \ln x < x^{1/2}$ and $\frac1{1+x^2} < \frac1{x^2}$ for $x \ge 1$,
$$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{x}dx < \int_1^\infty \frac{x^{1/2}}{x^2}dx=2$$

thus, converging.